# Samsung galaxy s9+: how to order screen unlock options

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-9

In my screen unlock options, I have iris scanner, face recognition, fingerprint scanner, pattern and password/security pin. I have all of the options set up. However, 95% of the time when I try to unlock it either ask for security pin or pattern. Maybe only 5% of the time it asks for iris scanner/face recognition. However it never asks for fingerprint scanner to unlock the phone.

I want to order these options so that whenever I try to unlock the phone it first ask for

1. Fingerprint scanner,
2. If no 1 fails, it ask for iris/face recognition scanner
3. If above fails it ask for pattern
4. Lastly if above all fails, it ask for password/security pin

Is there any way to order these options to unlock samsung s9+ phone?